# Java Files in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

In `netbeans` I can see two different icons in front of two different java files which are
[image]
and
[image]
What is the difference between them?

Comment: The first is a regular java class file with a `main` method, the second is a swing form file with a `main` method. Whenever you see the green arrow, it means the class has a `main` method

Comment: @peeskillet and what is the difference btw a 'swing form' file and a regular java file?

Comment: Swing form is a when you select New -> Swing --> JFame Form. It's for the gui builder.

Comment: Yah I know that but what difference is there between them, i mean in looks and in code

Comment: The only difference is that the swing form is compatible with the builder tool and had a common form file. You can look in the directory and you will see the .form file that goes with the .java file

Comment: That .form file allows you to use that particular .java file with the design tool. The form files are exported to the jar because they don't matter in production. Only in development

Comment: EDIT: _" The form files are **not** exported to"_

Comment: @peeskillet Could you please compile all the comments into an answer, So that i can give you some recognition for the answer

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/work_java_code.htm#r1c1-t5 is the place you can see those meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [image] is a regular java class file with a `main` method, the [image] is a swing form file with a `main` method. Whenever you see the green arrow, it means the class has a main method

> *"and what is the difference btw a 'swing form' file and a regular java file?"*

Swing form is a when you select New -> Swing --> JFame Form. It's for the gui builder.

> *"Yah I know that but what difference is there between them, i mean in looks and in code"*

The only difference is that the swing form is compatible with the builder tool and had a common .form file. You can look in the directory and you will see the .form file that goes with the .java file.

That .form file allows you to use that particular .java file with the design tool. The form files are not exported to the jar because they don't matter in production. Only in development.

As far as both .java files go, they are no different. A .java file is a .java file, and any valid Java code can be placed in either.

Answer (score 0):

The swing JFrame Form, contains a generated code that translate each Swing component drag and drop to generated code into a method called init() -as i remember- and this method is called in the constructor of this class, Note: this generated code is not editable.

The regular java file, is a blank file that contains a code you can write.